# UINavigationController add Right button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I know this question was asked many times, but I didn't find my situation:
I have 1 UINavigationController in Main window. Main Window сontains also UITableView. When i select row, NavigationController pushes another UIViewController with nib. This UIViewController doesn't have Navigation controller, it contains only UITableView inside.

Here is screenshot of this UIViewController:

[image]

This is not Main Window. Main Window contains UINavigationController with UITableView.

And here is question:

How to add UIBarButtonItem into NavigationItem when i'm in pushed UIViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside that detail view controller's .m file, create an UIBarButton instance and set it as self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem. You can do it in init method.

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title"
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                             target:self
                                                             action:@selector(someMethod)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
[barButton release];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(saveItem)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
[saveButton release];
```

add this in your viewDidLoad method to create a Save Button.

Answer (score 2):

The view controller still contains a UINavigationItem and it is usable since you were pushed into a UINavigationController.

So you can simply do the following In your viewDidLoad method

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = yourBarButtonItem;
```